# Psql output csv file formatting

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, cmd, psql

Trying to make batch file that will get query from script file and put results into csv.
Batch file code:

```
psql -h host -d test -U test -p 5432 -a -q -f C:\Users\test\Documents\my_query.sql TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ';' > C:\Users\test\Documents\res.csv
```

In result file I'm getting result like this:

```
select *

from public.test

limit 3

    id    |    name     | count_01
----------+------------+---------------+
 11021555 | a       |             1 |
 39534568 | b       |             2 |
 11695210 | c       |             3 |

(3 rows)
```

How to get only script results without rows count and symbols like '|' or '+' and using ';' delimetres as in the usual csv file?

Working script:

```
psql -h host -d test -U test -p 5432 -q --quiet --no-align --field-separator=';' --file=C:\Users\test\Documents\my_query.sql --output=C:\Users\test\Documents\res.csv
```

Comment: Have you try "`--no-align`"  and  "`--field-separator=`" options?

Comment: Pretty sure you are getting the output of whatever is `my_query.sql` and never getting to the `COPY`. Add the contents of `my_query.sql` to your question.

Comment: Have you used the site search facility at the top of the page, when seeking examples of the use of the [available options](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html), you should have read? The first hit I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1120109).

Comment: Using `--field-separator=,` will only work reliably if the data contain no commas...

Answer (score 2):

From PostgreSQL v12 on, you can use the CSV output format of `psql`:

```sh
psql --quiet --csv --file=my_query.sql --output=res.csv
```

`--quiet` suppresses the `psql` welcome message.

Comment: When trying to add '--csv' getting an error 'psql: illegal option -- csv'

Comment: Then you are using a version older than v12 of `psql`.

Answer (score 0):

Should work with

```
psql -h host -d dbname -U user -p port -a -q -f my_query.sql -o res.csv --record-separator=',' --csv
```